# React.js using JQuery to Post Django got 403

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, frontend

I know this should be csrf problem. But it works differently on different port.

The Django server is on 8000 and then I test the front end on both 3000 and 8000, I got:

When I test front end on localhost:3000, I can get the post work;

When I test front end on localhost:8000, I get 403;

```
$.post("http://localhost:8000/todos/", {title:this.refs.title.value,text:this.refs.text.value });
```

Any ideas how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are reporting a 403 Forbidden, I would presume you're actually having a [CORS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdjango%5D+cors), not csrf.

I'd recommend installing [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) and whitelisting your frontend on port 8000 in the settings.